# Add UIImage Overlay to a UITableViewCell's imageView.image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image-processing, uiimage

I have a mainly transparent image which I would like to add as an overlay to a UITableViewCell's imageView.image.

However I don't know how to do this. Do I need to merge the images? Or can I just add one on top of the other?

If you could provide code on this matter, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work it out:

```
[cell insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ListViewAlbumOverlay.png"]] belowSubview:cell.imageView];
```